# jquery why doesn't this text show up

Tags: jquery

I am trying to teach myself jquery, (not so successfully so far)  why doesn't the div with id fill get updated when i click submit?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>              
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#go").click(function(){
      $("div#fill").load('test1.txt');
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>                            
  <form name="login"> 
    <label><strong>Administrative Login </strong></label>                              
    <p>Username:</p>                
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" />            
    <p>Password</p>               
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
    <br>                     
    <input type="Submit" id="go">
    <div id="fill"></div>
```

Comment: What type input is `#go`? Does the text file exist, are you sure of that?

Comment: it was type "submit", i think the text file exist

Comment: are you trying to load a text file or what ????

Comment: yes i want to replace the contents of the div with the text just to practice jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the default action of the submit button by returning false in the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#go").click(function() {
        $("div#fill").load('test1.txt');
        return false;
    });
});
```

By returning false, the form is not being submitted normally, the browser stays on the same page and the AJAX call that you are performing to fetch the `text.txt` file from your server has enough time to execute.

As an alternative I would recommend you subscribing to the submit event of the form instead of the click event of the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("div#fill").load('test1.txt');
        return false;
    });
});
```

This will ensures that the AJAX call will be executed everytime the form is submitted, not only if the submit button is clicked. But of course that will depend on your requirements.

Comment: ah... ok is this standard practice to use a submit button in this fashion?

Comment: That, or you change your input type to a button, which to me sounds like a better choice as that's what they're primarily there for.

Comment: @user557862 no this is not, that's why I recommended using `type="button"`. However that's up to you ;-)

Comment: @user557862, this will depend. If you want to AJAXify some form it is standard practice, yes. But really it will depend on what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: when I changed from the input, and instead went out of the form and created a button, it worked, it still didn't work with your solution above

Comment: one more question if I load a PHP file, can I fill the div with html as well as information from my mysql database?

Comment: I like better the second version, are you sure that returning `false` on click event will prevent the form to submit?

Comment: returning false didn't work for me, but can someone answer the question about the php file? should i use load() or get() for that?

Comment: @Minkiele, returning false from an event handler in jQuery prevents the default action from being executed. Then it will depend on what is the default action and which event you subscribed to. But, yes, if you subscribe to the submit event of a form and return false from the handler you are stopping the form from submitting and the browser from redirecting away.

Comment: @user557862, both `.load` and `.get` will send AJAX requests to the server. The first will directly inject the result into the selected element, whereas in the second you will have to subscribe to the success callback and decide what to do with the results of this AJAX request.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, I know that, I was only concerned about the first chunk of code, the one with the click event bound to the submit button. Returning false on click will prevent the form to submit. [Example from jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrPrF/)